# Access JavaScriptSerializer in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, serialization

I have a json array which I serialize`, how do I access it in the javascript. 
I am using javascript`amcharts`and want to pass`vb.net` array to the javascript charts.
The code is provided below:

**VB**

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    DataSetToJSON()
End Sub
Public Function SelectChartData(ByVal Name As String) As DataSet
    Dim sqlCmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim myData As New DataSet

    sqlCmd.CommandTimeout = 1200

    sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    sqlCmd.CommandText = "SelectAmChartdata"

    sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar)
    sqlCmd.Parameters("@Name").Value = Name

    Dim da As New dsSV1TableAdapters.tblGeneralTableAdapter

    da.Adapter.SelectCommand = sqlCmd

    sqlCmd.Connection = da.Connection
    sqlCmd.Connection.Open()
    da.Adapter.Fill(myData)

    sqlCmd.Dispose()
    sqlCmd = Nothing

    da.Connection.Close()
    da.Connection.Dispose()
    da.Connection = Nothing

    Return myData

End Function

Public Function DataSetToJSON()
    Dim dt As DataTable
    ds = SelectChartData("Weather")


    Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)

    For Each dt In ds.Tables
        Dim arr(dt.Rows.Count) As Object

        For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
            arr(i) = dt.Rows(i).ItemArray
        Next

        dict.Add(dt.TableName, arr)
    Next

    Dim json As New JavaScriptSerializer
    Return json.Serialize(dict)

End Function
```

**ASPX**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

//var chartData =  **Access Serverside Array**

    window.onload = function () {
    var chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
    chart.dataProvider = chartData;
    chart.categoryField = "country";
    chart.marginTop = 15;
    chart.marginLeft = 55;
    chart.marginRight = 15;
    chart.marginBottom = 80;
    chart.angle = 30;
    chart.depth3D = 15;

    var catAxis = chart.categoryAxis;
    catAxis.gridCount = chartData.length;
    catAxis.labelRotation = 90;

    var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
    graph.balloonText = "[[category]]: [[value]]";
    graph.valueField = "visits"
    graph.type = "column";
    graph.lineAlpha = 0;
    graph.fillAlphas = 0.8;
    chart.addGraph(graph);

    chart.write('chartContainer');
}
</script
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could dump the serialized data directly into an ASPX page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var my_data = <%= DataSetToJSON() %>;

</script>
```

Or you could use in the ASPX page:

```
<input type="hidden" id="my_data" clientidmode="static" runat="server" value="" />
```

And in the codebehind:

```
my_data.Value = DataSetToJSON();
```

You can then use `document.getElementById('my_id').value` to pull the data, decode it using something like `JSON.parse` and pass it in to your chart.

Comment: thank you that worked great. A different problem I'm having is with my array, currently my array is passed as var chartData = {"tblGeneral":[["USA","100"],["RSA","80"],["RUSS","99"],["UK","70"],["AUS","60"],["GER","180"],["SWISS","50"],["FRA","30"],null]};

Comment: How could I pass the array with the Field names as below, it seems the chart requires that                                                     var chartData = {"tblGeneral":[[country: "USA", visits: "100"],[country:"RSA",visits:"80"],[country:"RUSS",visits:"99"],[country:"UK",visits:"70"],[country:"AUS",visits:"60"],[country:"GER",visits:"180"],[country:"SWISS",visits:"50"],[country:"FRA",visits:"30"],null]}; Thanks once again.

Comment: You would need to transform the data yourself, such as - http://www.pastepal.net/view/3d3021b6

Comment: Thanks @Lloyd your a life saver